# How to disable popups when opening a file Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

In a VB.NET program, I try to open an Excel file but I receive the following error message:

[image]

I use the `Microsoft.Excel.Interop` library to read the Excel file.

When I perform `Workbooks.Open()`, Excel displays this message:

```
This copy of Microsoft Office is not activated.
```

How can I bypass or disable this popup while still editing in Excel?

Here is my code:

```
Public Shared Sub WriteDataExcel()        
    Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

    Try
        oExcel.Application.Visible = False
        oExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        oBook = CType(oExcel.Workbooks.Open(pstrExcelPath), Excel.Workbook)
        oSheet = CType(oBook.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    Catch ex As Exception
        OutPutErrLog(ex)
    End Try
End Function
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: To disable the Dialog, you can renew your license. Or prompt your customer to do it. Adding code to your app to detect Dialogs creation and push their Buttons seems, meh...

Comment: Hello ThaiNC. Can you please read your question again. I don't understand what you want. A sentence must have a subject and a verb. If writing some long sentence is too complicated, can you split them ? Can you also separate your lines so that text is more readable. Can you give which text is displayed with your error's message ?

Comment: @Jimi How do I add the code? can you help me?

Comment: @schlebe Sorry my english is not good.
I have attached the photo in here. The error appears as such.
https://www.google.com/search?q=popup+active+office+2016&sxsrf=ALeKk01Fr7McA-TxI2fdzgc24gRFKxCTlQ:1585805384815&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje6JO1gcnoAhW9xYsBHXfYBW0Q_AUoA3oECAwQBQ&biw=1536&bih=722#imgrc=oph4DQaEJcb41M

Comment: @TahiNC. I have improved (I hope), your question in adding new-line characters, in adding some highlight, in adding error message, etc. When my post has been accepted, you can use it to change some little important things that I have forgotten. I hope that is helping you. Don't hesitate to open the modified question to see how I have added some formatting enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to use an OpenSource library as [NPOI](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/NPOI) or [DOCX](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/DocX).

There are 2 importants things to known using Microsoft Word API

1. the API is not indepent of Word product and a licence is needed !
2. if your program is an important program that must be started every day on a server. You are not responsible of Microsoft product installation and one day a responsible of your company decide to upgrade Microsoft product without advising you and suddently your program crash ! I have experimented this case and my customer is not very happy. Since this incident, I try to not use Microsoft Office API.